# Mail address working despite not being registered in Exchange

Tags: email, exchange

**Tl;dr:** Changed SMTP server for a Exchange/Office 365, old mail address still usable (send & receive) while not registered in Exchange.

A few months ago, we took over the domain of one of our clients and upgraded them to  Office 365. In the process, we migrated the mailboxes from OVH to Exchange. While the domain is still registered via OVH, the mailboxes aren't anymore.

Our client discovered that one of their sales rep sometimes switched mid-conversation with a client to an old mail address that shouldn't be working anymore.

We checked in Exchange, that mail address doesn't exist as an account, mailbox nor alias.

By using some mail checkers on the web, we found that the domain was linked to what we set it up to (as it should), but that the address doesn't exist.

```
Mail server found for domain:
    - xxxxxxxxxx-com.mail.protection.outlook.com (priority 0, ip address: XX.XX.XX.XX)
Mailserver identification:
    XXXXXXXXX.mail.protection.outlook.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 2 Sep 2019 12:08:07 +0000

    E-mail address does not exist on this server
```

Still, that sales rep does receive and send mail from this address. Sending mail doesn't disturb me that much, spoofing exists after all, but it's the receiving part that I don't understand.

**What could be happening, for that address to still be usable?**

Comment: You should clean up your english, there are parts that just don't make sense. That being said, have you gone through DNS and verified all (A records, MX records, etc...) are correct?

Comment: @Larryc They are correct, that's why I'm puzzled by this situation. Sorry for the broken english, I though it was understandable, gonna re-read and correct it once more.

Comment: A fairly typical edge case when you switch mail providers (by changing the MX record) is when  the mailboxes and aliases at the old provider are not removed and disabled. Mail sent by other  users (in different domain names) at the old provider will not follow the updated MX record , but, since the domain is local to the old provider, messages will be delivered to those old mailboxes. - The rep may still be using and checking  his old mailbox in addition to his new Office365 mailbox.

Comment: I agree with HBruijn. It may happen because the old mailboxes and aliases haven't been removed. So that the account is still usable. You can check what server is handling email on your domain by doing a simple MX Lookup: http://mxtoolbox.com/

Comment: Looks like @HBruijn was right, the problem should be solved. I can't be certain at the moment as we don't have control over that mailbox, but it's the only plausible option I see. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear the issue has been resolved.